# How can I replace non-HTML tags or Custom Tags with html entity or htmlentities()?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have html text that is generated using ckeditor, in my text there are certain non-HTML tags which are not being displayed as it is considered as HTML tag.

I want to replace all my non HTML tag into html entities.
I did most of the tags with str_replace but now I have about 100 of different tags that are like `<ip address>, <user id>, <all |ORACLE_SID>` .

Can anyone help me with a regular expression or anything that help me out.

I have tried `DOMDocument` which treats these other tags as invalid tag and throws a warning.

I have tried regular expression but that is too risky as it can convert my HTML tags into HTML entity.

> Guys, I do not want to remove these non-HTML tags, rather I want to
>   preserve them by converting them to HTML entity, so that they can be
>   displayed on screen.

Comment: Is getting rid of them completely out of the question?

Comment: If you want to replace all you can use `htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');`? can you clarify a bit what you want? If you want to remove them all you can use `strip_tags()`

Comment: @antoni I want to convert non HTML tags or my custom tags into HTML entities so that I can display them on screen.

Comment: given your updates, try this function: ```function hhb_tohtml(string $str): string {
 return htmlentities ( $str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true );
}```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get actually how do you want to remove tags but using

```
echo htmlentities('<127.0.0.1>');
```

it will output ip address in opening, closing carets.

Answer (score 0):

if you want htmlentities to ignore your custom tags that happens to have special meaning in html, then no, i don't think htmlentities is customizable on that level, you'll have to use another html encoding function. but if your problem is that you have too many str_replace calls, just use strtr instead. for example, this entire thing:

```
$html=str_replace('<ip address>','127.0.0.1',str_replace('<user id>','1337',str_replace('<all |ORACLE_SID>','839781233213',$html)));
```

can be replaced with this 1 call to strtr:

```
$html=strtr($html,array(
    '<ip address>'=>'127.0.0.1',
    '<user id>'=>'1337',
    '<all |ORACLE_SID>'=>'839781233213',
));
```

which results in prettier code and smaller code and faster execution and avoids problems where the replace key of 1 replace is part of the replace value of another (in this case, str_replace will replace the replace value of the first 1, but strtr won't).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is with CKEditor, which encodes characters '<', '>', '/' into '&#60', '&#62', '&#47', respectively. So this would fix the problem:

```
CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin = false;
CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_processNumerical = false;
```